# We are facing the issue with IE 11, .html() tag is not loading the data in div section. i.e. $("#contentArea").html(data);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

We tried with below options to resolve the issue like which did not work.

```
document.getElementByID('contentArea').innerHTML = data;
```

and

```
var container = document.getElementById("contentArea").parentNode;
container.innerHTML= data;
```

It is working other browsers like IE7, IE8,IE9,IE10, & Mozilla Firefox and chrome except IE11. While debugging the line by line code in JavaScript file we identified the issue with .html(data).

Comment: The `.innerHTML` mechanism does work in IE11.  Are there errors reported?

Comment: Would be good to see HTML as well and "we identified issue with .html(data)?" have you added correct JS in question ? as one you tried u mentioned above does not have ".html(data)"

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: improve your question so we can try to help you. what is in your data variable?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the append() method as an alternative and see if it works.

http://api.jquery.com/append/